# How to reselect date from calendar control after validation failed?

Tags: .net, asp.net, calendar, controls

I have a textbox, an imagebutton, and a calendar control inside a user control to pick the date from calendar and set the selected date inside textbox. All works well except the validation. I tried to validate the textbox's value to be a valid date. If it is not a valid date, I want to reselect a date from the calendar, but it looks like if validation failed, I could not reselect date if I did not put a correct date inside the textbox. Basically, validation requires me to fix the invalid date first before I try to select a valid date, but I want to reselect when validation failed.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">    
    <ContentTemplate>        
        <div style="width: 400px">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>            
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/cal.gif" OnClick="ImgButton1_Click" />        
            <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" DayNameFormat="FirstLetter" Width="90px" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="11px" NextMonthText="»" PrevMonthText="«" SelectionMode="DayWeekMonth" SelectMonthText="»" SelectWeekText="›" CssClass="myCalendar" BorderStyle="None" CellPadding="1" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" Visible="False">
                <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="Gray" />                
                <DayStyle CssClass="myCalendarDay" />                
                <SelectedDayStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12px" />                
                <SelectorStyle CssClass="myCalendarSelector" />                
                <NextPrevStyle CssClass="myCalendarNextPrev" />                
                <TitleStyle CssClass="myCalendarTitle" />            
            </asp:Calendar>  
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="cusValidator1" runat="server" OnServerValidate="Customer_Validation" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblError" Text="invalid input" Visible="false" runat="server" />
        </div>    
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

       protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    // Set Date Time value into the TextBox control    
            TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");        
            // Hide the Calendar control after selecting the date    
            Calendar1.Visible = false;    
        }
        protected void ImgButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
             Calendar1.Visible = !Calendar1.Visible;        
        }
```

Comment: Aren't you answering your own question. If the text in the textbox isn't a valid date then how can you reselect it? Am I missing something?

Comment: @madcapnmckay: I am of the same opinion
@Cindy: how do you reselect a date when the text in the textbox isn't a valid date to begin with and thus doesn't match?  Is entering a date by hand necessary?  Can you just use a label instead and store the date from the datepicker in the label so that the user can't enter an invalid date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved. Just by setting different validation group name, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Acutally I figured this one out. By adding validation group to only textbox and required validators, not the calendar control. It will allow me to reselect from calendar control even if textbox value is not valid.

Comment: But here I have another question. Everything is working except that if the textbox value is not valid and I can see the error message. But if I clicked the submit button outside this user control, it wont submit the form But MY Error message disappeared. Ideally I want my validation error message stays even I click the submit button.